# Existe a possibilidade de adicionar bibliotecas não nativas ao python?

Tags: python-3.x, importação, módulo-python

Estou com uma dúvida se existe a possibilidade de adicionar uma biblioteca não nativa do  `python`.

Exemplo, estou usando o  `NetworkX` para criar grafo, para isso preciso instalar a biblioteca e tudo mais.

Estou querendo adicionar diretamente esta biblioteca ao programa, caso eu use em outro pc para eu não precisar mais instalar ela, meio que já encapsular esta biblioteca ao código.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Existe a maneira de você adicionar ela diretamente ao seu código do projeto e deixar ela, de certa forma, já embedada.

Ou você pode utilizar uma pasta em seu projeto com um nome que você quiser e no python você colocar:

```
from modulo import modulo
```

Isto deve funcionar em seu caso!

Comment: obrigado pela resposta.
Mas como seria essa primeira maneira que voce respondeu? Obrigado

Comment: Você pode me informar se ela se encontra na mesma pasta que o seu código, qual o nome da pasta e do código?

Comment: Eu tenho o framework baixado que é o Networkx, eu posso colocar ele na mesma pasta onde está meu código, o nome da pasta é paa, o nome da pasta do framework é networkx e o código é redefluxo.py.

Comment: provavelmente você terá de executar:

   from networkx import *
ou
   from networkx import networkx

Comment: Ocorreu uns erros, de acordo com sua recomendação, irei colocar o erro:
``'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rede_fluxo_max.py", line 2, in <module>
    from networkx import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documentos/paa/networkx/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    import networkx.utils
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documentos/paa/networkx/utils/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from networkx.utils.decorators import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documentos/paa/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 7, in <module>
    from decorator import decorator
ImportError: No module named 'decorator' ``

Comment: tenta colocar:`from networkx import *`

Comment: Ou dê uma olhada neste link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python]